# cannot render script in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to integrate LinkedIn follow button in my website made in nextjs.
These two scripts return a follow button with follower count on it and I want to add it into my header.

`<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script> <script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="76160368" data-counter="bottom"></script>`

The issue is that when every I refresh my page this works but when I click on any button on my page it just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Use the script tag like this :

```
import Script from 'next/script'


<Script id="linkedinScript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">lang: en_US</Script><Script id="yourScriptId" data-counter="bottom" type="IN/FollowCompany"></script>
```

Comment: This is working just fine but the button is coming at the end of the webpage. Even after adding the script to the right place in the header.